# How does a public key authenticator work? (as opposed to public key signatures)

Tags: authentication

In the documentation for djbs library NaCl under the headline **Security model** you can read that the library provides public key authentication without non-repudiability (http://nacl.cr.yp.to/box.html). How is this possible when the parties have no shared symmetrical secret?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skimming the [NaCl PDF](http://cr.yp.to/highspeed/naclcrypto-20090310.pdf) I think they just generate such a shared secret.

In an interesting fashion:

> Section 5: Alice, using Alice’s secret key a and Bob’s public key B, computes a 32-byte secret k. Bob can compute the same secret using Bob’s secret key b and Alice’s public key A.

Using that shared key they then seed a pseudorandom generator. The first 32 bytes of which are used as the authenticator secret. And the rest of which are used for actual encryption.

## DJB's definition

[DJB's definition on Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/sci.crypt/73yb5a9pz2Y/LNgRO7IYXOwJ):

> What is a public-key authenticator? It's a secret-key authenticator,
>   with a key derived from g^xy, where g^x and g^y are the public keys of
>   the sender and the receiver.
>
> If you were already planning to encrypt the message, using another key
>   derived from g^xy, then you don't have to do any extra public-key work.
>   A secret-key authenticator is easier to implement than a public-key
>   signature, and it takes less CPU time to compute.

I guess if he had named it "public-key *derived* authenticator" instead then the idea might have been more obvious.